# Values from Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

**I have a function that return array values as JSON object:**

```
function keywords(){

    $keywords = array ('29254' => array('JOIN', 'PIN', 'WITHDRWAL', 'BALANCE'),
                        '24254' => array('UPNIN', 'PEIN', 'BALANCE'),
                      );

    return json_encode($keywords);
 }

print_r(keywords());
```

**The result:**

```
{"29754":["JOIN","PIN","WITHDRWAL","BALANCE"],"24254":["UPNIN","PEIN","BALANCE"]}
```

I want to get the array with the key `29254` only.

**I tried this:**

```
$data = json_decode(keywords());

print_r($data)[29254];
```

...but I still get all of them.

Comment: print_r($data["29254"]);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
$data = json_decode(keywords(), true);

print_r($data['29254']);
```

or try this

```
$data = json_decode(keywords());
print_r($data->{29254});
```

json_decode will return values inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one:

```
   return json_encode($keywords[29254]);
```

output:
    ["JOIN","PIN","WITHDRWAL","BALANCE"]

Answer (score 0):

```
function keywords($data=''){

    $keywords = array ('29254' => array('JOIN', 'PIN', 'WITHDRWAL', 'BALANCE'),
                        '24254' => array('UPNIN', 'PEIN', 'BALANCE'),
                      );

    return !empty($data) ? json_encode($keywords[$data]) : json_encode($keywords);
 }

print_r(keywords(29254));
```

Comment: why adding a default value to `$data` as this will throw a notice ?

Comment: Thank you @AymDev, I haven't noticed, i have updated the answer